# What is the route to a postdoc without a PhD supervisor?

Tags: phd, postdocs, recommendation-letter

I really like my PhD! I'm a 3rd year and need to begin thinking about next steps.

I've found the area of physics I can truly get behind (and I've engaged with a lot of different topics, in and out of physics). The catch? I have no scientific supervision.

My funding arrangements 'changed' somewhat; my funding is no longer tied to a national laboratory and the associated horrors. This left only one supervisor - a busy professor who runs many things. I used the opportunity to radically change the focus of the PhD and **I'm exploring methods that my supervisor has no clue about whatsoever**. My supervisor doesn't try to direct me/the work, instead choosing to review any additions to my thesis. We get on okay, and I like this arrangement. I feel that I'm producing new results (truthfully not so much of that before), and I feel sure I want to continue in physics (not necessarily in the exact area I'm in; just so long as it uses the methods I'm becoming involved with).

With a view to postdocs, I feel I'm nailing the independent research skills - from setting the research question to its execution, I'm a one-man-research team. However, I cannot escape the concerns that I could be a *better* researcher if I had an expert guide me. On a purely practical level, I also need references to apply for a postdoc. Where is that going to come from now? Most of the group are spread out in various (external) labs, so I don't interact with anyone except my supervisor now.

**What path should I consider taking if I want to remain in research given little-to-no supervisor input?**

Comment: Offhand... I'd worry that you're orphan-izing yourself. No one will be able to give you substantive letters of recommendation, comments on your work, etc. Eventually, sure, we all do want to be independent of "judgement", but, to my perception, you are trying this far toooo early.

Comment: "I don't interact with anyone except my supervisor now." This is the core of the problem, the rest of your concerns are consequences of this. Obtain travel funding, visit other groups working on your topic. In particular, visit the groups where you would potentially like to do a postdoc. Work on establishing in-person relationships with significant researchers in your subfield.

Comment: What university are you at that they think this is OK? You should never have fallen between the cracks like this if you're at a reputable university. You should definitely voice your concerns to the department head or the ombudsman if you have one. You should be assigned an advisor that is able to guide you through your PhD.

Comment: @CrisLuengo falling through the cracks is a surviving strategy that may bring you very far. It allows you to get rid of unnecessary bureaucracy and things "you absolutely must do according to the program/plan/project" which 99% of the time turns out stupid useless byzantinism, instead focusing on things you absoultely need to do for your own progress. Let all PhD get fully funded and fall through the cracks, finding their way their own way!

Comment: which field are you in?

Comment: @EarlGrey That is the most bizarre statement I have seen in a long time. A PHD advisor is not going to have you fill out forms, they’re going to teach you how to do research. Without an advisor you still have to do all the same paperwork to get your PHD, but without any help. Imagine spending 4 years writing a thesis, and then the reviewers are like “no, this is shite, this is not a PHD.”

Comment: @CrisLuengo we are talking about falling through the cracks, not becoming an heremit, i.e. still participating to conferences and publishing papers ... just without a supervisor fully understanding of the topic: PhD is therefore facing the "crowd" with their own ideas and no backing: what could be a possibly better gym for ideas?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's strange to respond to "I used the opportunity to radically change the focus of the PhD" with "What university are you at that they think this is OK?". How is it the university's fault that the OP proactively decided that they want to change the topic of their PhD? Or is the university somehow obliged to provide supervision for whatever topics a PhD student decides to pursue on their own in the middle of their PhD studies?

Comment: @Adam from what you’re saying I’m guessing this is not true everywhere, but yes, I expect the university to be responsible for the education of their students.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Me too, but to repeat myself: how is it the university's fault that the OP unilaterally decided to change the topic of their PhD in the middle of their PhD studies? If I get accepted to do a PhD in black hole physics but suddenly in the middle of my PhD I decide to start working on fluid dynamics, how is it the university's responsibility to provide me with an advisor on the new topic?

Comment: @AdamPřenosil That is not something a PhD program should accept, the research program should be set by the student together with the advisor (or advisory team in some places). But anyway that is not what happened here. "Funding arrangements changed", OP's research was with a national laboratory (a 3rd party outside the university), and that collaboration was terminated. The university should now pick up this student and help them with a new supervisory team and probably a new research plan, not let them fend for themselves.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil At the university where I worked at, this situation would not have been allowed at all. When a student had a fallout with their advisor, when a student wanted to do something totally different, when an external research partner disappeared out of the equation, a solution was always found, with a new advisory team, a new research direction, whatever. But there I had never seen a student in a situation without proper advisors. You simply couldn't graduate that way, because the advisors direct the studies.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think you are missing the part where, although the change in funding arrangements was due to circumstances beyond the student's control, the decision to "use the opportunity to radically change the focus of their PhD" came from the student. They were not left hanging, they were assigned a different advisor on a presumably related topic, but instead they "took the opportunity" to do something else. The university might be to blame for the funding issue, but I find it unreasonable to blame the university for the consequences of the OP's decision to change topics.

Comment: In what area of physics are you working? How soon is your defense? Are you looking for a postdoc in Europe or in the US?

Comment: @AdamPřenosil after the lab pulled their involvement, my supervisor asked me "now what's the plan?". I don't know if that was rhetorical, but as it happened I did. He could have said "actually, I'm your supervisor and I want you to do X". However, this guy has never given me scientific supervision - that was always the national lab supervisor. I'm used to being invited to lunch to tell him what I have been doing, but not to expect any actual guidance. So frankly I'm not surprised that A) he asked me what to do next B) didn't stop me when I said I had an idea.

Comment: @Michael_1812 I've got 1.5-2 years before I *have* submit my thesis. I probably don't mind whether the US or Europe. In terms of what I do, whilst I don't want to go into specifics as I'm now concerned my situation is so different (ergo identifyiable) that I'll just say that I'm working in a computational area. Although I wouldn't describe myself as a theorist (to me that's pen & paper), I think in practise a lot of computational (computing-based) physics research is hosted under the auspicses of theory groups. Does make me worry - they're not exactly known to be fountains of funding!

Comment: @RealDisinformation The area of quantum computing is now developing at such a pace, and is funded so generously on both sides of the pond, that almost anyone who is proficient in computing and acquainted with quantum physics has their chance in that area. Some food for thought...

Answer (score 35):

I think you're in a dangerous spot. A PhD is a research apprenticeship. If an electrician apprentice told you that they don't actually have anyone guiding them but they're doing a real good job connecting wires together and feeling really confident they found electricity because they're seeing sparks creating lots of light and everything and that seems like most of the job, I think you'd be worried.

Lots of people come here with problems finding a letter of recommendation after their PhD because their advisor suddenly turned evil when the student wanted something reasonable like to graduate, or stopped responding, or died. You may have the same problem as them or your token advisor may write some brilliant letter for you despite their lack of involvement, who knows. I'm more worried that you aren't getting the day to day research mentorship. I'm worried when your thesis is done you'll find it's not actually as good as you thought it was, for reasons you could never have been expected to grasp on your own. Research isn't easy. PhD programs wouldn't exist if everyone could just automatically do research on their own without guidance.

I don't know how you should move to find a real advisor, but I think it's something you should consider *necessary* and act accordingly. Maybe collaboration is the way to go, and maybe your advisor can help you find collaborators that you can work with more directly. This might disrupt your preferred workflow but I don't think that workflow is sustainable at the career stage you're at. Maybe I'm wrong, but if I'm right I'd hate for you to have lost the chance to move on.

Comment: "If an electrician apprentice told you that they don't actually have anyone guiding them but they're doing a real good job connecting wires together and feeling really confident they found electricity because they're seeing sparks creating lots of light and everything and that seems like most of the job, I think you'd be worried."  Right, but you'd be reassured if that apprentice electrician passed the summative assessments and got the NVQ; similarly, you'd be reassured if the PhD student passed the PhD and/or got some peer-reviewed papers published, no?

Comment: There are many instances of bad or very light supervision of PhDs, several of the students are good and well qualified  anyway and some will make their way into an academic career (personally I had a supervisor who did what he could and did it well, however due to illness he was basically absent 80% of the time I did my PhD). I think this answer is too negative on the possibility of doing good work and learning well without much supervision.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I worry a bit about survivorship bias in that sort of thing. For every one that continues on academia how many don't even finish the PhD? It's possible of course but I don't believe it's the best path for someone early enough in the process to adjust.

Comment: @BryanKrause Well, some people also fail despite having good supervisors. I agree that the probability for success is lower without; what I write isn't meant to dispute that, but here we apparently have somebody with ambition and drive. Nobody here can assess their abilities and the quality of their work, so I don't see much reason for discouraging them, given that positive examples exist.

Comment: Generally I'm rather wary of the mindset according to which the quality of a young researcher is mainly a product of the quality of their supervisor. I am aware that some people in admission commissions look at the names of the recommendation letter writers in the first place in order to assess an applicant. I think that this is very bad for academia and part of why some fields are rightly accused of being old (white) boy networks.Of course being realistic I have to acknowledge that it happens in some places, but good luck to everyone who gets in using a more self guided approach!

Comment: @ChristianHennig It's not just lack of supervision, they're not interacting regularly with anyone who can give them feedback.

Comment: I'll add that a lot can go wrong in research that makes it hard to publish, whether that's fair or not (unless you're willing to [make](https://stanforddaily.com/2022/11/29/stanford-presidents-research-under-investigation-for-scientific-misconduct-university-admits-mistakes/) [stuff](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/2023/6/23/alleged-data-fraud-gino/) [up](https://www.science.org/content/article/errors-found-dozens-papers-top-scientists-dana-farber-cancer-institute)). It's not that I think supervisors should have as much weight in assessment as they do, but sometimes that's all you've got.

Answer (score 8):

I also did a PhD in a group where there was no expertise in what I did, only tangential one, making me a bit of a scientific orphan.

I am still in academia and I think doing OK, so it is possible to get a postdoc after a PhD like that. I will describe my experience, which may be generalizable, or may be I was lucky, take it with a grain of salt.

What I did after my PhD is find a postdoc in exactly the field I did my PhD in. This helped because even with little interaction with researchers on my field, I still had 4 years of work experience on it, so you learn something. Using @Bryan's allegory, I would actually trust an electrician that learned everything by themselves, if they have been learning for 4 years and can show successful completed projects (papers). That said, moving into a group doing the same thing I had been working on for 4 years helped me pick up a ton of things that I should have learned in my PhD, but hadn't, so with a bit of hard work, (I think) I got myself into the expected level of a supervised PhD+postoc by the end of my postdoc, i.e. I used the postdoc opportunity to catch up with everyone else.

While your concerns for finding a postdoc are completely valid, it will indeed be much easier to find one if you already show expertise on the exact field of the job, rather than a tangential one. Reference letters are super important, but proven experience doing the actual job counts more, I think.

Good luck!

Comment: My experience resonates with yours, although I did less of the catch-up during the postdoc, because I was already thinking what to do next, so I skipped the catch up and I worked on the part "how to optimize complementary knowledge to get fundings". 
To add another anedoctal point: I got a professorship afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

In my view a major thing is that you need to make yourself known. Particularly go to conferences, present your work, and talk with people who do related things. If at all possible it is also good to do visits or even internships at research groups that do related works. Also always look for funding opportunities. Contacts are needed for moving forward in Academia, as is initiative in aspects other than just doing good research and learning, particularly when it comes to securing funding. A supervisor who helps you to get to the right places and know the right people can help a lot. If you don't have such a supervisor, you've got to try a bit harder, but for sure it can work out.

Comment: I would add to "talk to people who do related things" the sentence "and try to arrange a visit at their group of some weeks/months. OP is a bit late to do so, but it is very helpful for OP to spend some time in a group doing what OP is doing, to learn some "tricks of the field" and even  to get a possible reference (I stress the *helpful*, not necessary).

Comment: @EarlGrey Good point, added.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is important to be aware that your current perception of your situation is just that, your perception. It may or may not be what your advisor views you as (nor is it true that their perception of you is accurate).

I can give you some anecdotal experience from my end as both a graduate student and an advisor.

As a graduate student I was very independent, though I had a great relationship with my Ph.D. advisor. I managed to publish prolifically with his help, but my projects were tangential to his (in my fields, this is less common, you work as a lab group not as individual researchers). I was frustrated things would take longer because "he had no clue about all these advanced things I knew". In reality he was focused on other items which were more germane to his interests, and as I look back now, equally if not more interesting to what I came up with. So while I did learn independence, I likely could have benefited more from his direct expertise. It's been a long time since I graduated now, but I still keep in touch with my advisor - as a friend. We email back and forth, we text, ask each other for advice etc. I can truly appreciate how absolutely brilliant this man is beneath his soft-spoken and easy-going demeanor. I wish I took more advantage of that as a student. I think at this stage of my career I am more successful than he was (numbers wise), but I don't think I will ever have his deep insight, which I lost out on because I was just too smart to humble myself and learn from him.

As an advisor, I have had brilliant independent students, and I have also had un-coachable students. I have had more of the latter than the former. You may think you are a brilliant independent researcher, but you may just be perceived as un-coachable, but smart enough to get through a PhD (which is your case? I have no clue, that's between you and your advisor). Do not fall into the latter trap. Take advantage of the support structure inherent to being a student and learn from it, and harness it so you can grow into a well-rounded researcher.

People tend to repeat situations, and you may just find yourself as a postdoc with an advisor who also has "no clue whatsoever" about all the brilliant things you do. Maybe the role of the advisor is not to know every minutiae of your approach, but rather help guide you towards becoming a better independent researcher - part of that is you actively and openly engaging with them towards that goal.

Answer (score 1):

Get in touch with the people in physics that would care about your work. If your work is on arxiv, send a link around. Go to small conferences where you can network with people who might be potential postdoc advisors. If they find you smart and personable in face to face interactions, then a letter becomes less important.

Answer (score 1):

#### Find co-authors in your field

Others have pointed out the precariousness of your approach. However, if you intend to pursue this course, there are tactics to minimize the risk, and this is one of them.

A senior co-author can provide many (though not all) of the things an absent supervisor can. They can teach you certain tricks of the publication process, put you in touch with other people in the field, and provide tailored advice. More importantly, they can support you in your search for the next job.

This isn't easy to do at first. It helps if you have some results (pre)-published already. After that, you just need to be bold. Go to conferences and workshops. If there's budget for it, an internship/research visit at a lab in your field might be a good idea (and your supervisor is likely to see the benefit of it).